# Nuget not searching in custom package sources

Tags: nuget-package, visual-studio-mac-2022

I have added 2 custom package sources. If I search in nuget package manager, I find my package. If I install the package it fails with the following error:

```
Restoring packages for .NETStandard,Version=v2.1...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mypackage.test/index.json
  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/mypackage.test/index.json 125ms
Resolving conflicts for .NETStandard,Version=v2.1...
Unable to find package mypackage.test. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'FormsApp1'.
```

In the logging I see that package manager only searches in `nuget.org` and not in my custom sources.

I am using **VS for mac 17.4.2, Nuget 6.4.0.117**

**Questions:**

1. How do I tell package manager to also search in my custom sources?
2. How do I install a specific version of nuget on Mac? I would like to try version 6.3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this issue by installing [VS2019](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=Visual%20Studio%202019%20for%20Mac).**

When installing VS2019 it replaces VS2022. But you can install VS2022 Preview alongside. After installing VS2019, the package manager works correctly in VS2019 as well as VS2022 Preview.

So I guess the installation of VS2022 is broken as it was a fresh install on a new laptop.